# How to align in gather environment and keep the equation and description in the same page

Tags: equations, align, description, gather

I'm writing my equations and description using the `gather` environment. But I'd like to align to the left the equation parameters description, and keep the equation and the description together in the same page (could be a new page, like latex do woth figures)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\begin{gather*}
A_{T}=\pi\left(\dfrac{D}{2}\right)^{2}=\pi\left(\dfrac{0,15~m}{2}\right)^{2}=0,018~m
\intertext{Onde:}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
$A_{T}$:    &   Área da seção transversal $\mathrm{(m^{2})}$\\
$D$:        &   Diâmetro (m)
\end{tabular}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I'd leave these details for the final revision of the document. If you happen to get a bad break with `\intertext`, set the relevant penalty to infinity.

In the example I used `\shortintertext` from `mathtools` that seems better here.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker={,},
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\begingroup
\postdisplaypenalty=10000
\begin{gather*}
A_{T}=\pi\left(\frac{D}{2}\right)^{\!2}=\pi\left(\frac{\SI{0,15}{\meter}}{2}\right)^{\!2}=
\SI{0,018}{\meter}
\shortintertext{Onde:}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
$A_{T}$:    &   Área da seção transversal (\si{\meter\squared})\\
$D$:        &   Diâmetro (\si{\meter})
\end{tabular}
\end{gather*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I also used `siunitx` for the units and added a negative thin space to the exponents in order to push them a bit nearer the parentheses.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    [...]
    Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{gather*}
        A_{T}=\pi\left(\dfrac{D}{2}\right)^{2}=\pi\left(\dfrac{0,15~m}{2}\right)^{2}=0,018~m
        \intertext{Onde:}
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
            $A_{T}$:    &   Área da seção transversal $\mathrm{(m^{2})}$\\
            $D$:        &   Diâmetro (m)
        \end{tabular}
    \end{gather*}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: excellent suggestion. First I tried the @egreg answer but mathtools was causing issues with other packages like calc, such that, the latex unit mu wasn't working as expected. But your solution doesn't require mathtools and does the same as shortintertex.